# Is the vector space complete under this norm?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

We have $C^2[0,1]$ under the norm: $\|f\|=\|f\|_\infty + \|f''\|_\infty$. I know that it shouldn't be complete because we have no information about first derivative but I'm struggling to find an example which shows that. Also a general proof that $C^k[0,1]$ is complete iff all the derivatives are included in the norm would be great.

Comment: You need to find a sequence of functions $\{f_n\}$ in $C^2[0,1]$ such that $$\lim_{n,m\to\infty} \|f_n-f_m\|_\infty +  \|f_n''-f_m''\|_\infty = 0$$
but has a pointwise limit $f(x):=\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x)$ which is not in $C^2[0,1]$.

Comment: @Math1000 But there is no such sequence. $\ddot\smile$.

Answer (score 1):

You can find constants $A$ and $B$ such that $\|f'\|_{\infty}\le A\|f\|_{\infty}+B\|f''\|_{\infty}$, by using the following
\begin{align}
   (b-a)f'(x)&=(b-x)f'(x)+(x-a)f'(x) \\
          &= -\int_{x}^{b}\frac{d}{dt}\{(b-t)f'(t)\}dt+\int_{a}^{x}\frac{d}{dt}\{(t-a)f'(t)\}dt \\
        &=\int_{x}^{b}\{f'(t)-(b-t)f''(t)\}dt+\int_{a}^{x}\{f'(t)+(t-a)f''(t)\}dt \\
        &=f(b)-f(x)-\int_{x}^{b}(b-t)f''(t)dt+f(x)-f(a)+\int_{a}^{x}(t-a)f''(t)dt \\
        &=f(b)-f(a)+\int_{a}^{x}(t-a)f''(t)dt-\int_{x}^{b}(b-t)f''(t)dt.
\end{align}

Comment: Oh, so this means that the space will be complete! It turns out that the first derivative is not needed.

Comment: @user275181 : That's it.